# What are the differences between using ItemsSource and foreach loop to assign data in a ListView?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, listview

Is there any differences between following code snippets?
I'm using VS 2010, .NET 4, WPF

Code Snippet 1:

```
  List<EPutAway> listEPutAway = new List<EPutAway>();
  // assign some data in listEPutAway here
  lvPutWaySearch.ItemsSource = listEPutAway;   // lvPutWaySearch is a ListView
```

Code Snippet 2:

```
  List<EPutAway> listEPutAway = new List<EPutAway>();
  // assign some data in listEPutAway here
  foreach (var ePutAway in listEPutAway)
                {
                    lvPutWaySearch.Items.Add(ePutAway); // lvPutWaySearch is a ListView
                }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a **very big difference**.

In the first scenario, you are [binding to the `listEPutAway` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx). This means that if the collection implements [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx), any changes to it will automatically be reflected in the control that binds to it.

Of course, in this specific example, `List` (which class exactly is that?) probably does not implement this interface. Usually when binding you elect to bind to an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) for this specific reason.

In the second scenario, you provide the list of items to the control manually. The data in the control is then completely independent from anything else that might be going on in your application.

One of the major attractions of WPF is specifically support for data binding, so "the WPF way" is the first scenario (and declaring the binding in XAML as well).

As a sidenote, you should have in mind that it isn't possible to use `Items` (manual population) and `ItemsSource` (data binding) at the same time.

Comment: I'm not using `INotifyCollectionChanged`. I want to generate a ListView when a Button is clicked. And first time when I click the button it works fine(for Code Snippet 1 and 2) but when I click the button second time I get 'NullReferenceException' exception if I use Code Snippet 2 in the button's Click event. In this perspective what are the differences.

Comment: @DavidWebb: Impossible to say unless you provide more information (which value is `null` exactly?). As a general note: *all* scenarios, including yours here, can be architected to work with data binding instead of the straight-on procedural code. It's simply a matter of getting used to it. I would know since the same happened to me when I first came in contact with WPF.

Comment: Probably you you are suggesting to use MVVM pattern. And I think thats the best suggestion if someone is using WPF. My problem is solved.

Comment: Another benefit of using data binding is you leverage the power of the VirtualizingStackPanel in the ListView. This means if you have 10,000 items, only the ones that are visible are drawn.